# code composer - unresolved symbols remain

Tags: c, code-composer

I try to read gyro data. When I build, I always get some link error. My output, as follow;

> **** Build of configuration Debug for project mpu6050_v1 ****
>
> "C:\ti\ccsv7\utils\bin\gmake" -k -j 4 all -O  'Building file:
>   ../main.c' 'Invoking: ARM Compiler'
>   "C:/ti/ccsv7/tools/compiler/ti-cgt-arm_16.9.4.LTS/bin/armcl" -mv7M4
>   --code_state=16 --float_support=FPv4SPD16 -me --include_path="C:/Users/yilmaz/workspace_v7/mpu6050_v1" --include_path="C:/ti/TivaWare_C_Series-2.1.4.178" --include_path="C:/ti/ccsv7/tools/compiler/ti-cgt-arm_16.9.4.LTS/include"
>   --define=ccs="ccs" --define=PART_TM4C123GH6PM -g --gcc --diag_warning=225 --diag_wrap=off --display_error_number --abi=eabi --preproc_with_compile --preproc_dependency="main.d_raw" "../main.c" 'Finished building: ../main.c' ' ' 'Building target: mpu6050_v1.out'
>   'Invoking: ARM Linker'
>   "C:/ti/ccsv7/tools/compiler/ti-cgt-arm_16.9.4.LTS/bin/armcl" -mv7M4
>   --code_state=16 --float_support=FPv4SPD16 -me --define=ccs="ccs" --define=PART_TM4C123GH6PM -g --gcc --diag_warning=225 --diag_wrap=off --display_error_number --abi=eabi -z -m"mpu6050_v1.map" --heap_size=0 --stack_size=512 -i"C:/ti/ccsv7/tools/compiler/ti-cgt-arm_16.9.4.LTS/lib" -i"C:/ti/ccsv7/tools/compiler/ti-cgt-arm_16.9.4.LTS/include" --reread_libs --diag_wrap=off --display_error_number --warn_sections --xml_link_info="mpu6050_v1_linkInfo.xml" --rom_model -o "mpu6050_v1.out" "./main.obj" "./tm4c123gh6pm_startup_ccs.obj"
>   "../tm4c123gh6pm.cmd" -llibc.a
>   -l"C:/ti/TivaWare_C_Series-2.1.4.178/driverlib/ccs/Debug/driverlib.lib"
>
> undefined first referenced symbol in file 
>   --------- ---------------- MPU6050DataAccelGetFloat ./main.obj  MPU6050DataGyroGetFloat ./main.obj  MPU6050DataRead ./main.obj 
>   MPU6050Init ./main.obj  MPU6050ReadModifyWrite ./main.obj
>
> error #10234-D: unresolved symbols remain error #10010: errors
>   encountered during linking; "mpu6050_v1.out" not built
>
> > > Compilation failure makefile:143: recipe for target 'mpu6050_v1.out' failed gmake[1]: *** [mpu6050_v1.out] Error 1
> > >       makefile:139: recipe for target 'all' failed gmake: *** [all] Error 2
>
> **** Build Finished ****

My code as follow.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "sensorlib/i2cm_drv.h"
#include "sensorlib/mpu6050.h"
#include "sensorlib/hw_mpu6050.h"


//
// A boolean that is set when a MPU6050 command has completed.
//
volatile bool g_bMPU6050Done;

void MPU6050Callback(void *pvCallbackData, uint_fast8_t ui8Status);
void MPU6050Example(void);


/**
 * main.c
 */
int main(void)
{



MPU6050Example();


    return 0;
}

//
// The function that is provided by this example as a callback when MPU6050
// transactions have completed.
//
void MPU6050Callback(void *pvCallbackData, uint_fast8_t ui8Status)
{
    //
    // See if an error occurred.
    //
    if(ui8Status != I2CM_STATUS_SUCCESS)
    {
    //
    // An error occurred, so handle it here if required.
    //
    }
    //
    // Indicate that the MPU6050 transaction has completed.
    //
    g_bMPU6050Done = true;
}

//
// The MPU6050 example.
//
void MPU6050Example(void)
{
    float fAccel[3], fGyro[3];
    tI2CMInstance sI2CInst;
    tMPU6050 sMPU6050;

    //
    // Initialize the MPU6050. This code assumes that the I2C master instance
    // has already been initialized.
    //
    g_bMPU6050Done = false;
    MPU6050Init(&sMPU6050, &sI2CInst, 0x68, MPU6050Callback, 0);

    while(!g_bMPU6050Done);

    //
    // Configure the MPU6050 for +/- 4 g accelerometer range.
    //
    g_bMPU6050Done = false;
    MPU6050ReadModifyWrite(&sMPU6050, MPU6050_O_ACCEL_CONFIG, ~MPU6050_ACCEL_CONFIG_AFS_SEL_M,
    MPU6050_ACCEL_CONFIG_AFS_SEL_4G, MPU6050Callback, 0);

    while(!g_bMPU6050Done);

    //
    // Loop forever reading data from the MPU6050. Typically, this process
    // would be done in the background, but for the purposes of this example,
    // it is shown in an infinite loop.
    //
    while(1)
    {
        //
        // Request another reading from the MPU6050.
        //
        g_bMPU6050Done = false;
        MPU6050DataRead(&sMPU6050, MPU6050Callback, 0);

        while(!g_bMPU6050Done);

        //
        // Get the new accelerometer and gyroscope readings.
        //
        MPU6050DataAccelGetFloat(&sMPU6050, &fAccel[0], &fAccel[1], &fAccel[2]);
        MPU6050DataGyroGetFloat(&sMPU6050, &fGyro[0], &fGyro[1], &fGyro[2]);
        //
        // Do something with the new accelerometer and gyroscope readings.
        //
    }
}
```

Please help me, any advice. I have trying for days.

Comment: your main is empty !! ??

Comment: I filled. but i get same results. I have some linked error but i count find. please help me.

Comment: You have to compile and link `sensorlib/mpu6050.c` to your binary

Comment: The error log points the problem stems from linkage meaning symbols are not found, likely not generated. Kolay gelsin. En passant, try proposal of @Ctx(+1'ed one), it's the solution, at least IMO.

Comment: Thanks for everyone. eyvallah :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added mpu6050.c and i2cm_drv.c as linked file. project->addfile->linked_to_file and ok.

[solution](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1n6GN7bkkCROaSHNMN-gRszggtSkiOcNr)

Thanks for help. I solved the problem as in comments